# How to decode this png file?

Tags: image, image-processing, png, decoder

Can anyone please help on how to open this png file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23248082/TEST.PNG

Also it would be great if you can tell me how it is enrcrypted or why its not opening.
It opens fine only with Meditech client. It seems Meditech is encrypting in someway.
I tried with different viewers and also tried converting it into differen format but so far no luck. 
Iam also a newbie in this area. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: Looking at it [with tweakpng](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) it seems the format is deliberately corrupted for proprietary use. There's a wrong CRC for the palette (correcting it does no good) and an invalid chunk count.

Comment: @RogerRowland That deserves to be an answer

Comment: @leonbloy ... and now it is ... :-)

Comment: Hmmm Wondering how come meditech shows it correctly :-/

Comment: @torqueabhi A PNG reader might opt for not checking CRCs. In any case the behaviour of reader with any invalid format is unpredictable - it might just work. If that's intended, if Meditech is using its own PNG format, then it's not PNG anymore - no wonder only Meditech can read it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it with [tweakpng](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) it seems the format is deliberately corrupted for proprietary use. There's a wrong CRC for the palette (correcting it does no good) and an invalid chunk count.

Answer (score 1):

If your Meditech is the EHR (Electronic Health Record) system then you will only be able to accurately view the image by accessing it from the system. All data is encrypted for the purpose of restricting access to patient records.